# Adding a Foreign Key from a SQL Dump fails

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to create a database from an SQL Dump.
I wrote it like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS rsa_database;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keys` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `public_key` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `private_key` varchar(30) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstname` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `k_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (k_id) REFERENCES keys(id)
);
```

But my MySQL Server throws this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 78: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys(id)' at line 1
```

I tried different notations and read some documentations, but I cant figure out my failure. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `keys` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, you need to quote it with backticks every time you reference the table named `keys`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `firstname` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `k_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`k_id`) REFERENCES `keys`(`id`)
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I found out, how to fix it, but not why I had to ;)

Comment: By default mysqldump quotes all table and column names with back-ticks, so I speculate that someone manually edited the file after it was generated.

Comment: My advice is to avoid using reserved words for table and column names. If you do that then you don't need to worry about this type of problem.